# Login to website from Clever internet suite

Tags: delphi

I am wanting to login to Facebook using clever internet suite and show the response for my profile page, yet I am unsure on what I am doing wrong the code bellow shows the login page response "Not" my profile page.

```
  clHttp.UserName := 'Example';
  clHttp.Password := 'Example';

  clHttp.Get('https://www.facebook.com/login');

  Memo.Lines.Add(clHttp.Get('https://www.facebook.com/me'));
```

Comment: FaceBook do not use HTTP authentication. See https://developers.facebook.com

Comment: Is there a work around? @fpiette

Comment: I never tried, but maybe you could use a web browser component and automate it.

Comment: Whenever you see a "submit" button you're dealing with an [HTML `<form>`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), which either starts a [HTTP `GET` or `POST` request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods), filled with all the form's fields (i.e. `<input>`). Read [the vendor's articles](https://www.clevercomponents.com/articles/article009/httppost.asp), learn internet basics.